# Creating array for use in CodeIgniter Activerecord input_batch

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to do an array which is suitable for the Codeignitors input_batch activerecord. I'm quering a Link table so I have onlu two columns - user_id and group_id and because I'm gonna insert information only for a certain user the user_id is the same every time, and I need to change only the group_id.

Here is what I've done:

```
 $str = $dataGroups['groups'];
 preg_match_all('/[0-9]/', $str, $matches);
```

this part I just take the info for the groups which is in form of numbers displayed '1,2,3,4...' and take only the numbers which are the values of the foreign key 'group_id'

After that all I do is creating the array that I'm gonna use for the input_batch record doing this:

```
$count = count($matches[0]);
  $datas = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i)
    {
    $datas[] = array("user_id"=>$data['id'],"group_id" => $matches[0][$i]);
    }
  return $datas;
```

here $data['id'] is the user_id and it should be the same for all elements.
At the end I have to get the same structure as shown in the CI tutorial(I guess so at least) which is:

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);
```

(Haven;t modify it, I just quote it here), but when I var_dump($datas) I get null. So my logic is leaking somewhere.

Thanks for help
Leron

Comment: You want to make updateUserGroup() function ? =)

Comment: No, I change the logic, after every correction all the data for the groups will be deleted and then inserted again.

Comment: Ok, it works, here is what I've done $id=$data['id'] and then $datas[] = array('user_id' => $id, 'group_id' => $matches[0][$i]);

Comment: ops, my mistake, yes, insert_batch. I'm little dizzy by now. Anyways, the array obv the problem was somewhere in the quotation marks...

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = $dataGropus['groups']; //  comma separated list
$arr_groups = explode(',', $str); // split the string into an array based on the comma
$datas = array(); // initiate param, not really necessary in PHP, just for clarity's sake
$user_id = $data['id'];

foreach($arr_groups as $group_id)
{
    $arr_temp = array("user_id" => $user_id, "group_id" => $group_id);
    array_push($datas, $arr_temp); // you could use $datas[] = $arr_temp, but I like array_push
}

return $datas;
```

Here's how I would do it. There's no reason to use "complicated" preg_match trickery when you can use `explode()`.

If this still isn't working, make sure $str and $data['id'] are valid.